# How can I create my custom Reset Password Token

Tags: magento2, rest-api, token

I am using plugin

```
<type name="Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement">
    <plugin name="custom_change_reset_password_link_token"
            type="Vendor\MobileApp\Plugin\AccountManagementPlugin"
            sortOrder="10"
            disabled="false"/>
</type>
```

and using Around on method **aroundChangeResetPasswordLinkToken** but problem is it is working on APIs but when I try to access the reset link on web it always gives me error

```
Your password reset link has expired.
```

Here is my implementation

```
/**
* @param AccountManagement $subject
* @param callable $proceed
* @param string $customerId
* @param string $newPasswordToken
* @return bool
*/

public function aroundChangeResetPasswordLinkToken(
    AccountManagement $subject,
    callable $proceed,
    $customerId,
    $newPasswordToken
) {
    $customToken = ( string ) $this->random->getRandomNumber( 100000, 999999 );
    return $proceed( $customerId, $customToken );
  }
```

When I pass a 6 digits string directly it works for example

```
    return $proceed( $customerId, "123456" );
```

IDK what's the issue please help, Thanks in Advanced

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Request Customer Password Reset Token Using Magento 2 API
Provided below is the complete structure of the Magento 2 API request to get the customer password reset token:

Method: PUT

URL: store_url/rest/V1/customers/password

Body:

```
{
  "email": "ram.sharma@gmail.com",
  "template": "email_reset"
}
```

Step 2: Use Customer Password Reset Token to Set New Password Using Magento 2 API

Method: POST

URL: store_url/rest/V1/customers/resetPassword

Body:

```
{
  "email": "ram.sharma@gmail.com",
  "resetToken": "0:3:DufpYnLrA+Kw5jmJUd6171AQSU2jgO+1AOp4AiIeibTHq5jgve+7ZBDvI62ihr1tDeBxYSmvtNILoeIk",
  "newPassword":"testing@789"
}
```